# Make a nested field not searchable in elasticsearch 5.6

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a field which is nested inside other field, I want to make that field not searchable my mapping looks like this

```
dataset": {
    "properties": {
            "identifier": {
                    "type": "text"
            },         
            "title": { 
                    "type": "text",
                    "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets"
            },         
            "description": {
                    "type": "text"
            },         
            "refinement": {
                    "type": "text"
            },         
            "isAbout": {
                    "type": "text"
            },         
            "primaryPublications": {
                    "type": "text"
            },         
            "aggregation": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "include_in_all": false,
                    "store": "no"
            },         
            "availability": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "include_in_all": false
            }          
    }
```

}

when I get the mapping using curl command I can still the fields for which I marked include_in_all false. is there any other way to make the field non-searchable.

Answer (score 1):

I used "[enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/enabled.html)" of properties

> Elasticsearch tries to index all of the fields you give it, but sometimes you want to just store the field without indexing it

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "user_id": {
          "type":  "keyword"
        },
        "last_updated": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "session_data": { 
          "enabled": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```